# Word for someone who experiences an emotion?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to fill out the blank in this sentence:

> The right kind of anger encourages its ___ to react in the correct way.

Currently, I'm using "holder", but that doesn't fit well. "Experiencer" isn't a word. "Feeler" usually means something else, and although it technically fits as "someone who feels," it just doesn't sound right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could rephrase so that you don't need a word for it: "The right kind of anger encourages one to react in the correct way."

Comment: How about 'agent'? Does it actually need to be synonymous to someone experiencing an emotion, or only fit the sentence you provided? If the latter, can you edit your title to reflect that?

Comment: Not _agent_. _Agent_ is for actions, not emotions. The correct technical term in semantics is _Experiencer_. It **is** an English word, and that's what it means. It's common with predicates like _sorry, sad, prefer, furious, puzzled, a nervous wreck_ etc. Many of them are adjectives, but not all.

Comment: I jumped to conclusions—experiencer _is_ a word! Thanks @JohnLawler. I'll probably use this, feel free to make it an answer.

Comment: @Joachim I don't think agent is the best word here (for reasons John Lawler explained), but thanks for the suggestion. I do want a word for someone experiencing an emotion. This is mostly out of curiosity but partially because I like this sentence structure.